# T-SQL conditional UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

If I have an update statement like this:

```
UPDATE Message 
   SET Subject = Subject
```

...will SQL Server actually perform an update or is it smart enough to recognize that no update is really needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is actually smart enough to recognize that the update is required. There are many more factors at play, a trivial example being triggers.